# Debug Messages in Gazebo 4?

Tags: gazebo-4

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have a robot model that worked on Gazebo 2.2.3 on a different computer that I've been trying to port over to Gazebo 4. I copied the entire folder over to Gazebo 4's model directory and changed the SDF tags to 1.5 for both .sdf and .config files. For some reason, whenever I try to spawn the robot in Gazebo 4 through the menu, gzclient just terminates and gives me a generic "process has died" message. Is there somekind of debug model in Gazebo 4 that will allow me to determine what exactly is wrong with my model or Gazebo? I'm going to ask another question related to the Robot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7292/debug-messages-in-gazebo-4?/) by [K. Zeng](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/835/k.-zeng/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 103 on 2014-10-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

start gazebo with

```
$ gazebo --verbose
```

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2014-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2